# Multilingual Taxonomy Search

Tags: user-profile, taxonomy, multilingual

I don't know whether this is possible in SharePoint or not but can someone please confirm about this.

I have created a multi-lingual term set so for ex. for a term called energy I added a **Spanish** term also called *Energía* now when I am tagging if I tagged a document with  Energy (or) Energía the document should appear on search, but its not happening like that. Is this default behavior can I achieve my requirement with any other way for more clear understanding I am attaching my terms

[image][image]

Comment: you would need that beyond tagging content to also run a full crawl.  go onto the SSA and under Managed Properties and see if you find your actual Managed Metadata column mapped. have a look at your Crawl Log see if no issues appear.

Comment: Hi Marius Thanks for the comment . But when i am searching after a full crawl for the tag  Energy in default laungauge (English ) the document is appearing .but when i am searching for Energia its not appearing ...also all these are terms so do i need to map every individual term if so can you please elaborate on that,..

Comment: have you simply tried with a site in another language (Spanish)? as SharePoint uses those labels particularly in that case

Answer (score 1):

I found some explanations on Timmy Gilissen's Blog of this behaviour:

MUI Managed metadata vs. Search
http://www.moss2007.be/blogs/timmy/archive/2011/12/01/mui-managed-metadata-vs-search.aspx

And a workaround

Multilingual Taxonomy Search
http://www.moss2007.be/blogs/timmy/archive/2011/08/01/multilingual-taxonomy-search.aspx

Hope it helps,

Cheers,

Stevan

Comment: Please give me a Chance to follow your links. I get a user-Login-prompt on both of the links! very Kind regards frm Austria