# Search Scopes Depending on User Profiles

Tags: user-profile, people-search

I had created 2 User Profiles one for Intranet and one for Extranet .Now when i am using profile search in my sites( i had created separate web applications for my sites for users depending on their domain) the results are showing user profiles form both of the domains is there a way i can limit that.

Regards
Anil

Comment: did you configure User profile service applications separately?

Comment: Yes Falak i had configured 2 User profile Service Applications ..For mysiteint I set User Profile Intranet as default and for mysiteext i set User Profile Extranet as Default

Answer (score 2):

On the same note as Per, because you already have 2 Web Applications for each of "My Sites", after configuring 2 Search SA's you would actually need to use the Service Connections under Manage Web Applications to establish the correct relationship for either the User Profile SA and Search SA (of course each Search SA is targeting apropiate Content Source or at least Shared Search Scope).

That is the intended usage of separation provided by using multiple Service Applications in SP 2010. In addition you could use PowerShell to Create custom groups and move your SAs appropiately (as here http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Give-your-SharePoint-2010-custom-Application-Proxy-Groups-pretty-names.aspx).

Comment: Thanks much Marius that solved my problem also thanks for the additional info..

Comment: Hi Marius Can you please go through my other question it would be really helpful if you can help me solve my other question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38979/multilingual-taxonomy-search

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up two Search Service Applications one for Intranet and one for Extranet. Then you can configure each mysite to it's own search application, which should then do the sps3 crawl against the corresponding mysite

Comment: Hi Per Can you please go through my other question it would be really helpful if you can help me solve my other question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38979/multilingual-taxonomy-search